# Using Cookie value from one ng-app in another ng-app in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

I know that it isn't good practice to have multiple ng-apps in a project but my project is divided into segments that aren't generally related to each other, plus I am left with more or less no other option.

My problem is the persistence of `ng-cookie` amidst two separate Javascript files. Let's say I have `dashboard1.html` that is linked to `controller1.js` and `dashboard2.html` linked to `controller2.js`.

Now, I want to access the cookie value of controller 1 in controller 2. When I try to do this the result says undefined and that means I cannot access the cookie value set by another Javascript file.

Please advise me how to solve this issue.

NOTE : Javascript files have respective ng-app defined and controller for each application.

This is Controller and `ng-app` part of one module.

```
var app = angular.module('mainpageapp', ['ngRoute','ngCookies']);
    app.controller('ctrlmainpage', ['$scope', '$timeout','$http', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', '$rootScope', '$cookies', function ($scope, $timeout, $http, $route, $routeParams, $location, $rootScope, $cookies) {
        console.log("Csadad");

        $cookies.myFavorite = 'TestCookie';
        var favoriteCookie = $cookies.myFavorite;
        console.log("Cookie" + favoriteCookie);
```

Now in this ng-app's controller I am setting a cookie, it works properly and I do get expected response on console. This is in file controller1.js

Now I am trying to access the same cookie in controller2.js that is all together bound by different ng-app.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'smart-table', 'ngCookies']);
var id = 'hasdh';
app.controller('dashmerctrl', ['$scope', '$timeout','$http', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', '$rootScope', '$cookies', function ($scope, $timeout, $http, $route, $routeParams, $location, $rootScope, $cookies)
{
    var favoriteCookie1 = $cookies.myFavorite;
    console.log("Cookie1" + favoriteCookie1);
```

Her I get undefined as output.

I want to access that same cookie in this file.

Comment: Does it work if you pass {path: '/'} as an option?

Comment: Can you provide your code? The ng-cookie directive sets a session-based cookie. You should be able to access it as normal. Also, have you thought of just setting document.cookie in your js instead?

Comment: @yts I don't get it yts. Pass the path `/` where?

Comment: @ChristianHill I'll update my question in 2 minutes.

Comment: @OneNote if you look here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies#put you'll see there's a third parameter which accepts an object. Pass in {path: '/'} as that object and see if that works.

Comment: @ChristianHill Works as expected. You can post that as an answer if you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys yts and Christian Hill. :)

Comment: Wait, what was the answer? Can someone please post the answer?

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to share data across tabs or domains you can give zendesk's "cross-storage" a try, just implemented it with AngularJS and it works like a charm.

it utilizes window.postMessage() technique to achieve this behavior.

link: [zendesk/cross-storage](https://github.com/zendesk/cross-storage)